# Displaying information from 1st object in a list in a GridView

Tags: asp.net

I have a list of customers, each of which has a list of transactions. What I need to show is the list of customers and the details of their last transaction.

I've retrieved the details into a List of Customer, each with a List of Transaction as a property (called Transactions)

I'm trying to show the data of the transaction, and I thought that I could bind to a data field of Transactions[0].TransactionDate, but the GridView doesn't recognise that. Is there some other syntax, is it not possible, or what's a good workaround for this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What you need to do is create a gridView rowDataBound event and in this event you can do something like this. The reason for this is as it will give you alot more control over the binding.

```
protected void gridView_RowDataBound(object sender, GridViewRowEventArgs e)
{
   if (e.Row.RowType == DataControlRowType.DataRow)
   {
      Customer> customer = (Customer)e.Row.DataItem; 
      Label lblTransaction = ((Label)e.Row.FindControl("LabelTransaction"));
      lblTransaction.text = customer.Transactions[0].TransactionDate;
      //do what ever you want to do here using the value of your label
   }
}
```

Comment: Don't mean to be too much of a pedant, but the line is (Customer)e.Row.DataItem. But thanks for the approach.

Comment: Yep your right i wrote the code from top of my head hence the silly mistake i have edited the code =o)

Answer (score 0):

You should be able to cast the dataitem, then read the value from that. e.g.

```
((YourClassName)Container.DataItem).Transactions[0].TransactionDate
```